# pipeline jenkins, вызов скрипта в цикле

Tags: jenkins, groovy

такой вот код на груви:

```
stage('----') {
    steps {
        script {
            def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(env.work_servers )
                for(item in jsonObj){
                        cmd("команда ... ${item.portrange}")
            }
        }
    }
}

// .........
@NonCPS
def cmd(command) {
    def result = ""
    if (isUnix()) {
        result = sh(
            script:command,
            returnStdout: true
        ).trim()
    } else {
        bat "chcp 65001\n${command}"
    }
    return result
}
```

приводит к такой ошибке
(это не полный error stack)

```
an exception which occurred:
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@248ff1dc
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LoopBlockScopeEnv@739a4c1
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@19e0b53b
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@7846515f
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@279090ba
in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@6048287a
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@63f4f64c
in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@4f87218
in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@4f87218
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:568)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1790)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
```

Пытался найти сам решение, где-то прочитал про @NonCPS, где-то пишут про def, но вроде я учел все рекомендации, а ошибка как была так и осталась. 
Если делать по отдельности, циклом например выводить инфу в лог по элементам, работает, отдельно и команда работает, а вот вместе нет.

Comment: полный error stack
https://pastebin.com/Gi3AvJML

Answer (score 0):

помогли на английском стеке, проблема в JsonSlurper, он не сериализуем, нужно JsonSlurperClassic юзать